# По клику на кнопку действие выполняется только со второго раза

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

А надо, чтобы выполнялось сразу же с первого раза.

```js
function f1(){
  //var pcolor = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
  var one = document.getElementById('one');

  if(one.style.background == 'black') {
    one.style.background = 'yellow';
    one.style.transition = 'all ease 1s';
  }
  else {
    one.style.background = 'black';
    one.style.transition = 'all ease 1s';
  }
  
  /*for(i=0; i < pcolor.length; i++) {
    pcolor.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  }*/
}
```

```css
p {
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p id="one"></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>

<button onclick='f1()'>Press</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что первый раз этого стиля еще не существует `<p id="one" style="background: black...` вам надо использовать `getComputedStyle()`, который берет стили из самого css.

> Метод getComputedStyle (IE9+, стандарт) позволяют получить реальное, применённое сейчас к элементу свойство стиля с учётом CSS-каскада и браузерных стилей по умолчанию.

Описание [`getComputedStyle()`](https://learn.javascript.ru/styles-and-classes#%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7-getcomputedstyle).

```js
function f1() {
  //var pcolor = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
  var one = document.getElementById('one');

  var computedStyle = getComputedStyle(one);
  console.log(computedStyle.backgroundColor);

  if (computedStyle.backgroundColor == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)') {
    one.style.background = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
    one.style.transition = 'all ease 1s';
  } else {
    one.style.background = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
    one.style.transition = 'all ease 1s';
  }

}
```

```css
p {
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p id="one"></p>
<button onclick='f1()'>Press</button>
```