# При нажатии на кнопку действие не происходит

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

При нажатии на кнопку прямоугольники должны стать синего цвета.

```js
function f1(){
  var pcolor = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
  for(i=0; i < pcolor.length; i++) {
    pcolor.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  }
}
```

```css
p {
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>

<button onclick='f1()'>Press</button>
```

Comment: однотипный же вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/742784/%d0%9f%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0/742791#742791

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [По клику на кнопку действие выполняется только со второго раза](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/742784/%d0%9f%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0)

Comment: Нет. Здесь вопрос указан для массива, потому что у меня с массивом не получалось, а в предыдущем вопрос - для идентификатора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pcolor[i].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
```

а не

```
pcolor.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
```

```js
function f1() {
  var pcolor = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
  for (i = 0; i < pcolor.length; i++) {

    pcolor[i].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  }
}
```

```css
p {
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>

<button onclick='f1()'>Press</button>
```